# InfluenceAnalysis of Meta-Analysis

Tags: meta-analysis

I am coming here hoping for help, which I could not find anywhere else. I am a physician doing research on prognosis of patients with certain autoimmune disease. Currently, there is variety of definitions of “response” to the current standard of care, however, no information is known about which one of these definitions performs the best.

I have decided to perform a meta-analysis of validations of these treatment response definitions, and I have decided to consider hazard ratios (HR), while this metric is the most frequently reported across different validations.

I successfully performed meta-analysis with random-effects (REML/Paul-Mandel procedure), although I still get high heterogeneity (I2>50%). Therefore, I have decided to perform an “InfluenceAnalysis” using function in R (dmetar), and in all but one “meta-analyses” I have acceptable results (max 1 influential “validation”/study/observation).

However, when analyzing validations of one particular definition, InfluenceAnalysis returns all but one as influential “validations”/observations and that comes somehow strange. In the forest plot, all of these HR are close to each other and only one looks like outlier, although using the above mentioned function, it is all the way around (not only the color, but also individual measures are behind thresholds).

I think there is something wrong with this. Does anybody know what? Thanks a lot! I really appreciate that.

[image: This is the forest plot]
[image: This is the results of InfluenceAnalysis]